# Presentation Component in Vue2

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I want to display all my forms and info pages in floating sidebox. 
I don't want to copy and paste the floating sidebox html to all the places. So I want to create a component which acts as container to my forms or info pages.
This is the sample code for form.

```
<div class="floating-sidebox">
  <div class="sidebox-header">
    <div class="sidebox-center">
      <h3 class="title">{{ title }}</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="sidebox-content">
    <div class="sidebox-center">
      <!-- This is the actual content. Above container code is common for all forms. -->
      <vue-form-generator :schema="schema" :model="model" :options="{}"></vue-form-generator>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="floating-sidebox-close" @click="cancel"></div>
</div>
<div class="floating-sidebox-overlay"></div>
```

In above code, I uses [vue-form-generator](https://github.com/icebob/vue-form-generator) to generate the form. The `floating-sidebox` elements are common for all forms and info pages. I want to abstract it by Presentational component.

How could I do it [Vue2](https://vuejs.org/)?

Comment: I'd use `vue-router` and include the above form component as part of the outer layout. Your page content would then be rendered in the `<router-view></router-view>`

Comment: Agreed with @Phil. I wrote a simple slides app called [**takahashi**](https://github.com/myst729/takahashi), you could see how I achieve it with vue-router.

Comment: @Phil Thanks. But in my case, I could not make it as separate router. It is is part of one route.

Answer (score 0):

Define a component that wraps all your "floating-sidebox" components. You can access the "floating-sideboxes" via this.$children and use their title etc. as navigation placeholder. Since $children is an array you can easily represent the currently visible entity with and index

```
...
data: function() {
   sideboxes: [],
   currentIndex: null
},
...
mounted: function() {
   this.sideboxes = this.$children;
   this.currentIndex= this.$children.length > 0 ? 0 : null;
},
...
computed: {
    current: function() {
       return this.currentIndex ? this.sideboxes[this.currentIndex] : null;
    }
}
```

You can then bind in the template of the wrapping view

```
<ul>
    <li v-for="(sidebox, index) in sideboxes" @click="currentIndex = index"><!-- bind to prop like title here --></li>
</ul>

<div>
   <!-- binding against current -->
</div>
```

JSfiddle with component https://jsfiddle.net/ptk5ostr/3/

Comment: What you mean by  "Define a component that wraps all your "floating-sidebox" components"? I don't have this component yet. I am confused. Can you please share jsfiddle?

Comment: i meant what i said. I know you don't have the component yet that's why I already sampled you three if it's possible methods. If you provide a fiddle for us we can easily make changes. I will not create a full fiddle on my own

Comment: Okay. I will create fiddle and share it with you.

Comment: I'm somehow not convinced I understood you correctly. I somehow thought you already have a component for your forms. so heres a simple copy paste approach to put your floating sidebox in a component. https://jsfiddle.net/ptk5ostr/3/

Comment: Awesome. It works for me. Instead of including vue form generator inside the floating sidebox component, can I have it in my main component. So I can put anything inside sidebox, not just forms. It is something similar to `trasclude` in angularjs